# How to handle multiple database with the same Core Data structure

Tags: swift, database

I am creating an App that permits to add various database for words learning. It works well for one database like (English to German traduction). I want now to use the same core data to add a complete independent database for traduction Spanish to french for instance. What is the best way to do it with Core Data?

My core data structure is the following: one entity called Word and attributes (name, definition, options). I would like to be able to add several different databases. I was thinking of a solution by adding a tag on the option attribute like -> (11 means first DB, 12 second DB, 13 third DB, etc) which requests me to filter each time on this tag to filter out the right database of words. I am not convinced that it's the best solution. What is the simplest and more efficient way to manage it?

Comment: I don't understand how you translation works but why not add a new attribute for language to your entity and have a fetch request that filters on language ?

Comment: imagine that the user will typically use the App to learn two different languages but he will build the database on his own (like a student who needs to learn vocabularies) by entering the words manually or from an existing file. The initial language typically english won't have translation in both other languages so I need to build separate database as those DB will be used randomly for questions. If one word is translated in one language but not in the other language it will be a blank field here, that's why I believe it's better to have 2 complete separate database.

Comment: Your use of the word database is a bit confusing but how would you connect one word in one language to the translated one in another language?

Comment: I can add, in general, how does such requests are handled in Core Data. It must be quite common like an App used by 2 different users on the same device and both wants their own personal data stored without mixing them?

Comment: Thanks for your support Joakim. A concrete example I want to learn french words in the finanical area (therefore a english to french database on this topic) and I want to learn german words on sports area (so a 2nd DB english to german on another topic), so you see both DB are separated.

Comment: Two users on the same device is not common so it is not supported by many apps I believe. As I see it one database with perhaps two entities (tables), one for the main language and one for storing the translations, would make most sense so I don't think we will get much further here. Good luck.

Comment: For others who have some ideas and can help. If I present my issue in another way, let's say I have two lists of words with translation (1. english-french, 2. german-spanish) those lists are not sharing any common words so in a spreadsheet type of storage you would use two separated sheets (-> two databases). In Core Data having such multiple databases seems not as simple as on spreadsheet as the structure is not done for that, so my understanding is to have all DBs together and filtering each time with tags? Am I correct?